# Error Handling Strategy in Salesforce -> ESB solution

Tags: integration, platform-event

One of the best `integration` strategy is `Fire and Forget` using `Platform Event(PE)`.

One of my use case is send `Order` and `Order line items` along with `Account` and `Credit Card` data to ERP system. For this I am using the `Platform Event` to send `OrderId` and then later `ESB` querying data with `orderId`.

In this process I am wondering how can we handle the `exception` if it occurs :

1. What if there is an `exception` in the process? It can be either business or technical `exception`.
2. What if `ESB` is down for more than 24 hours because life span of PE event is valid for 24 hours.
3. How can we use implement `retry` mechanism for those failed transaction?
4. For reporting is it good to use `Salesforce Custom Object` or should we use `GCP` or any other vendor to store and track all the traction.

I know no solution is perfect but wanted to know what would be the near perfect approach for this.

Comment: PEs are not guaranteed delivery. It is best to rely on DB state since this is guaranteed to be accurate (if the DML transactions succeeded).

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly recommend a redundant process that uses the Salesforce Replication API (getUpdated and getDeleted) if you absolutely need 100% guarantee. The sending of events is guaranteed within the limits, but there isn't a guarantee of delivery, for the reasons you mentioned. *Fire and forget* if great for many reasons, but delivery confirmation isn't one of the design goals.

These methods are available in both the REST and SOAP API endpoints. Check out the documentation for more information, but basically you can call this every five minutes with up to a 30 day retention. This is traditionally how Replication is handled, as it uses very few API calls and is 100% reliable.

This API can be called every five minutes and will never miss a record. You could still use PE as the primary mechanism, but this backup solution will help fill the gap to guarantee synchronicity within five minutes of coming back up. In most cases, five minutes is sufficient to meet business needs.